# Do I need to include a copy of the GPL / LGPL to every copy of my program?

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl

Is it necessary to include the GPL / LGPL license text to every distributed copy of my program? Or can I just put a link in the `About`-dialog?

Comment: Related: [Why do I have to keep my open source software license in the root?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/208238/why-do-i-have-to-keep-my-open-source-software-license-in-the-root/)

Answer (score 8):

#### TL;DR

Yes, because the link might become invalid in 5 or 10 years.

#### Detailed Version

Yes, this is necessary. You cannot just include a link pointing to the license text. The reason is clearly stated in the [GNU FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhyMustIInclude):

> **Why does the GPL require including a copy of the GPL with every copy
> of the program?**
>
> Including a copy of the license with the work is vital so that everyone who gets a copy of the program can know what his rights are.
>
> It might be tempting to include a URL that refers to the license, instead of the license itself. But you cannot be sure that the URL
> will still be valid, five years or ten years from now. Twenty years
> from now, URLs as we know them today may no longer exist.
>
> The only way to make sure that people who have copies of the program will continue to be able to see the license, despite all the
> changes that will happen in the network, is to include a copy of the
> license in the program.